# Export Test Execution result to excel through developer console/ SFDC org

Tags: unit-test

I just did ran all tests. Is it possible to export the results (all failures and successes) into an excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Its an Idea on Salesforce Community:

> ## [Export Test Results from Apex Test Execution Page](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000wkROAAY)
>
> Please provide an easy way how to export the test results directly from GUI. For example, as a test manager you're onboarding new functionality and want to see how your tests are doing before and after the new stuff is deployed. You plan to compare the results in Excel (same values as now displayed on GUI).
>
> Currently, you need to use either a SOQL query to ApexTestResult in Workbench, or copy from a print view. Print view is not good as it displays only a limited number of items, and selecting large number of items is arduous and error prone.